# How do I select a checkbox from flipkart brand filtering? I am automating using selenium. I wanted to click on the titan brand filter

Tags: python, selenium, filter, automation, flipkart-api

[click to see picture.**selenium**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5NVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@title="Titan"]
```

or

sometime click will be accepted only in input tag so you have find the child input tag:

```
//div[@title="Titan"]//input
```